# jNetPcap overloading openOffline()

Tags: java, jnetpcap

I'm looking for a way to overload this function in jNetPcap:

```
Pcap openOffline(String fname, StringBuilder errbuf);
```

I want to implement it in this way:

```
Pcap openOffline(InputStraem stream, StringBuilder errbuf);
```

I have downloaded the source code but this function is a `native` function, how can I go to the implementation of this function and try to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare your method as static and make a call to the original native method from within your method.

Something like

```
static Pcap openOffline(InputStream stream, StringBuilder errbuf) {
    String fname;
    doSomeThing(); //Extract a string from the inputstream and store it in fname
    return openOffline(fname, errbuf);
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is not what i'm looking for.
What i'm trying to achieve is to AVOID saving the InputStream to a file on the disk and work directly with the InputStream.
I'm trying to find a way to see how the openOffline(fname, errbuf) deals with the file and change to use the InputStream instead of the file.

Comment: I see, unfortunately, there seems to be no straight-forward way to pass an InputStream to JNI since there seems to be no corresponding JNI class. Passing as a jobject wom't give you access to it. I did a bit of googling and a tool named **JunC++ion** seems to be able to generate JNI code for InputStreams. See [here](http://codemesh.com/products/junction/)